# Running a python script inside HTML/PHP

Tags: php, python, html

I am trying to run a python script inside my webpage which creates this textfile that I later read using PHP. The PHP script to read the textfile works perfectly if I make a textfile on my own. But it doesn't work if I try to run the python script first (which should create the textfile and then read it).
Here's my code. I checked permissions and the path, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "abc.php">
<?php
  //creates or updates info.txt        
  shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /xyz/getinfo.py");

  $file = fopen("/xyz/info.txt", "r");
  //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
  while(!feof($file))
  {
    $f = fgets($file);
      echo $f . "<br>";
  }
  fclose($file);
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Permissions on *nix are complicated and are usually the problem. Check folder permissions of /usr/bin and /xyz . You're going to need read and execute permissions for the Python script and Python itself.

Comment: is the file created at all when you shell_exec the python script ? Try first by writing the file in /tmp write permissions are usually ok there

Comment: In addition to what Alex said, make sure the script is using the correct directory as it's working directory.

Comment: It seems your PHP script doesn't wait for the python script to finish running before it continues. That could lead to some problems.

Comment: drwxrwxr-x that's the permissions for /xyz,
drwxr-xr-x for /usr/bin

Comment: @Squazic how can I fix that?

Comment: In theory, the PHP does wait for the Python script to finish. Have you looked at the string returned by `shell_exec()` to see if there were any errors?

Comment: `shell_exec()` doesn't return anything. The python script does not have an output. It just retrieves some data from a remote server and stores this data in info.txt which I then read using `$file = fopen("/xyz/info.txt", "r")`.